# Androdi studio: count down timer doesn't count right from the second cycle

Tags: android-studio, countdowntimer

I have a program that should add a new marker to a google maps every few seconds, but when I complete the first cycle and restart the timer, it doesn't wait for the timer to end and goes directly to the timer `onFinish` method.

To make myself more clear: if the first time the timer waits 10 seconds before adding a new marker, the second time it will add the marker immediately, without waiting another 10 seconds.

I'll leave here my count down timer:

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownTot, countdownAt) {
 @Override
  public void onTick(long l) {
   Log.i("Timer", "a second has passed");   //basically, do nothing
  }

 @Override
  public void onFinish() {
   Log.i("Timer", "fine countdown");
   addMarkerToFirestore();   //start once the method that adds a new marker
   timerState = false;   //bool to know if the timer is still going or not
  }
}.start();
if (!timerState) {   //if the timer has ended
 countDownTimer.cancel();   //cancel the countdown
 countDownTimer.start();    //start a new countdown
 timerState = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you need to create a new `CountDownTimer` instance to start it again.

Comment: @Sergey Do you think it is possible to do so by using a class that creates a count down timer?

Comment: The class should create a new instance of `CountDownTimer` before it starts.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. This is surely a solution.